# Adding view causes "Child already has parent" error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I'm making a gallery app and adding image buttons dynamically using the code below, this works on one of my devices but on the other I get a

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.  
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3358):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3381)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3358):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3252)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3358):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3197)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3358):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3358):        at package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
```

error, but on the other device no problems at all and it runs fine. The one that it works on is running 4.1.2 and the one it crashes on is running 4.1.1 could this be it? the project's min and targeted sdk is 16

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Hook up clicks on the thumbnail views.


    imgHolder = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imgHolder);

    for(int x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
    {
        Log.d("Conor",files[x].getAbsolutePath());
        Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(files[x].getAbsolutePath());
        imgs.add(img);
        thumbs.add(new ImageButtons(this, files[x].getAbsolutePath(),x));
        thumbs.get(x).setImageDrawable(img);
        thumbs.get(x).setOnClickListener(onCl);
        imgHolder.addView(thumbs.get(x));
    }
    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
```

ImageButtons class that `thumbs` is an `ArrayList of

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class ImageButtons extends ImageButton{


    Resources res = getResources();


    public ImageButtons(Context context,String img,int id) 
    {
        super(context);
        XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(R.layout.imagebuttons);
        AttributeSet attributes = null;
        int state = 0;
        while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            try {
                state = parser.next();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }       
            if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (parser.getName().equals("ImageButton")) {
                   attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 

        setId(id);

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(context, attributes));
    }


}
```

thumbs is an `ArrayList<ImageButton>`
and line 74 refers to `imgHolder.addView(thumbs.get(x));

Again my question is why this works on some devices but not others

Comment: Please post the whole LogCat stack trace and make sure we can tell which line of your code the exception's thrown from. We also need to see information about `thumbs`, since it looks like the problem is that you're trying to attach `thumbs.get(x)` to multiple parents. It's entirely possible that the difference isn't Android but your runtime environment.

Comment: I have added the logcat stack trace, the line in question is imgHolder.addView(thumbs.get(x))

Comment: Yes, but what is the value type of `thumbs`? You're making assumptions about what piece of the code is important, and you're not providing what we need.

Comment: What do you mean by value type? I found no reference to it in the context of java when I googled it.  and what explicitly do you want to know about `thumbs` ?

Comment: Please post your entire class.

Comment: Thumbs is not a class, but an arraylist of `ImageButtons` which I have posted

Comment: Since you won't post your code, there's not much we can do to help. I suspect that you have an underlying bug in your `for` loop where you're accidentally reusing your `ImageButtons` instances and it's simply being triggered under different circumstances depending on which images are present (being iterated over) and under what circumstances the activity is being started or resumed.

Comment: what other code do you want? I have given the entire `onCreate`, and `ImageButtons`, nothing else gets called. I'm also thinking that you are trying to fix my code rather than answer my question, which is why does it work on one device and not on another

Comment: (1) Your whole class, not just an excerpt from a method where we can't even see the variable declarations, much less how you're handling them on previous calls. (2) I've said multiple times that it looks like a coincidence that it's device-specific and that it's triggered rather by the particular set of inputs and activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need some extra handling:

```
View v = thumbs.get(x);
ViewGroup p = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
p.removeView(v);
imgHolder.addView(v);
```

Comment: this was it, however I needed to add a try catch around it for the times when it wasn't happening